# Access permission in apache server CentOS

Tags: php, apache, centos6

I have installed a virtual machine CentOS 6.6. I also installed Apache, PHP, MySQL with `yum`.

I changed my document root from `/var/www/html` to `/www`
so I edited my `/etc/httpd/httpd.conf` and changed these two lines:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www/html">
```

I restarted apache and it was okay.

The problem occurred when I tried to open `http://192.168.199.90/phpinfo.php`.
I got:

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access /phpinfo.php on this server.

I tried to  disable SElinux in `/etc/selinux/conf` and change `enforcing` to `disabled`

I also tried this: `chcon -v -R --type=httpd_sys_content_t /www/`

And when I write `ls -laZ /www`, I have:

```
drw-rw-rw-. www  www  unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 .
dr-xr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:root_t:s0      ..
-rwxrwxrwx. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 phpinfo.php
drw-rw-rw-. www  www  unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 sites
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you all ,  i resloved it,

I changed the Current mode of SElinux
from `enforcing` to `permissive` by wrinting in the terminal :

`setenforce 0`

so when i write

`getenforce`  i get `Permissive`

I did also chmod 755 -Rf /www

;)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
chown -R apache:apache /www
```

or

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /www
```

BTW, **never** disable your `SElinux`

Comment: thank you @sky i reset it and changed SElinux current mode from Enforcing to Permissive

Answer (score 0):

Edit httpd.conf file, which is in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf. Add the below code.

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
#Options FollowSymLinks
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride None
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer  but it still the same problem did you mean <Directory "/www"> ,because i want to change it  to /www.

Comment: yes check with your .httpd.conf file for the directory permission.

Comment: the same error , ps: i used client machine to acces to the server

Comment: you can try by making `AllowOverride All`

Comment: thank you @Hardy Mathew i reset it and changed SElinux current mode from Enforcing to Permissive